# I am trying to implement a Variational Autoencoder. I am getting this error which I do not understand

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

```
Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6408bf8740d5> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 # Train the model
     10 #model.fit(x_train, epochs=10)
---> 11 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/model_2/tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 687, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 740, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 821, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 782, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-10-6408bf8740d5>", line 11, in <cell line: 11>
      model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1054, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 542, in minimize
      grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(loss, var_list, tape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 275, in compute_gradients
      grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
Node: 'gradient_tape/model_2/tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs'
Incompatible shapes: [640000] vs. [262144]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/model_2/tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4735]
```

This is my entire code

````
def load_data4():
    # Set path to directory containing images
    path_to_images = '/content/drive/MyDrive/heatsource_img/Practice'

    # Define regular expression pattern to extract coordinates
    pattern = r'x_(\d+)y_(\d+)\.jpg'

    # Initialize empty lists to store image data and corresponding coordinates
    images = []
    heatmaps = []
    coordinates = []

    # Loop through images and extract data and coordinates
    for filename in os.listdir(path_to_images):
        match = re.search(pattern, filename)
        if match:
            x_coord = int(match.group(1))
            y_coord = int(match.group(2))
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(path_to_images, filename))
            img = img.resize((200, 200))  # resize image to desired dimensions
            img_array = np.array(img)  # convert image to numpy array

            # Convert image to grayscale if it is not already grayscale
            if len(img_array.shape) == 3 and img_array.shape[2] == 3:
                img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

            # Check if image is of type uint8, and convert it to uint8 if necessary
            if img_array.dtype != 'uint8':
                img_array = img_array.astype('uint8')

            # Normalize pixel values of input image to be between 0 and 1
            img_array = img_array / 255.0

            # Add input image and corresponding output image to lists
            heatmaps.append(img_array)
            images.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_images, filename)))
            coordinates.append([x_coord, y_coord])

    # Convert lists to numpy arrays
    images = np.array(images)
    heatmaps = np.array(heatmaps)
    coordinates = np.array(coordinates)

    # Split data into training and validation sets
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, coords_train, coords_val = train_test_split(heatmaps, images, coordinates, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    return X_train, y_train, coords_train, X_val, y_val, coords_val
#Model
input_shape=(200,200,1)
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)

# Define latent variables
latent_dim = 10
mu = Dense(units=latent_dim)(x)
log_var = Dense(units=latent_dim)(x)

# Reparameterization trick
def sampling(args):
    mu, log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mu))
    return mu + K.exp(log_var / 2) * epsilon

# Sample latent variables
z = Lambda(sampling)([mu, log_var])

# Decoder
x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(z)
x = Dense(units=8 * 8 * 128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Reshape(target_shape=(8, 8, 128))(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='linear')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

# VAE loss function
def vae_loss(inputs, outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(inputs), K.flatten(outputs))
    reconstruction_loss *= input_shape[0] * input_shape[1] * input_shape[2]
    kl_loss = 1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    return vae_loss

# Compile the model
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.add_loss(vae_loss(inputs, x))
model.compile(optimizer='adam')

# Generate some data for testing

X_train, y_train, coords_train, X_val, y_val, coords_val = load_data4()
# Train the model

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))```
````

Comment: Do you really expect people to read those 2 pages worth of unformatted error output? Suggestion: since you are already using Google Colab, make a copy of your notebook, simplify it and provide a link, so people can (a) easily see the problem, and (b) experiment with your notebook to try to fix the error.